# how to stop featured products appearing on search results ? i'm using Wordpress Woocommerce with Mystyle theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have added featured products to my Woocommerce mystyle static front page via short code now it appears on every search result how can i remove it from my  search results ? also i am using woocommerce default shop page as my front page. don't know where to find the related php files for featured products and i'm not good at php

Comment: Does your plugin use custom post types for the products?

Comment: yes i guess woocommerce uses same table to store products that is used to store posts by wordpress

Comment: Inside an action hook like `wp_enqueue_scripts` you can check if the page being displayed is the shop page and then add the shortcode to it `<?php echo do_shcortcode("[featured_product...`